# Store ten most related items in structured array Python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I'm new to python and I'm trying to store in a (10 x 3) matrix the ten items with the highest correlation and for doing that I want to simply check the last row value (which is the minimum) and reorder the rows if a value with an higher value is inserted. My problem is that I can't figure out how to access a specific item in position (i,j) both for reading and modifying its value. Here it's my code:

```
dtype = [('tag1', 'S8'), ('tag2', 'S8'), ('correlation', 'f8')]
most_related_tags = np.zeros((10,3),dtype=dtype)

for i in tags:
  for j in tags:
     if(i['tag'] != j['tag']):
        correlation = tagCorrelation(tagsFile,str(i['tag']),str(j['tag']))

        if(correlation > 0):
            print most_related_tags[9,2]
            if(most_related_tags[9,2] < correlation):
                print "entered"
                most_related_tags[9,2] = correlation;
                most_related_tags[9,0] = str(i['tag']);
                most_related_tags[9,1] = str(j['tag']);
                most_related_tags = np.sort(most_related_tags,order='correlation')
```

The problem is that my program never enters the if statement, because most_related_tags[9,2] neither most_related_tags.item(9,2) returns the right object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the array that you created at the start?  It's a 10x3 array, where each element is a structured record - with 3 values

```
In [173]: most_related_tags
Out[173]: 
array([[(b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0)],
       [(b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0)],
       [(b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0)],
       ...
       [(b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0)],
       [(b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0)]], 
      dtype=[('tag1', 'S8'), ('tag2', 'S8'), ('correlation', '<f8')])
```

So you have to access individual tags with `most_related_tags[9,1]['tag1']` or something like that.

I suspect you really want an array of 10 items,

```
In [174]: tags = np.zeros((10,),dtype=dtype)

In [175]: tags
Out[175]: 
array([(b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0),
       (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0),
       (b'', b'', 0.0), (b'', b'', 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('tag1', 'S8'), ('tag2', 'S8'), ('correlation', '<f8')])
```

where you access individual tags values with `tags[9]['tag1']`, or a record with `tags[3]`, or all correlations with `tags['correlaton']`.

Then you should be able to set values with:

```
        if(most_related_tags[9]['correlation'] < correlation):
            most_related_tags[9]['correlation'] = correlation
            most_related_tags[9]['tag1'] = str(i['tag'])
            most_related_tags[9]['tag2'] = str(j['tag'])
```

or set the whole record with a tuple

```
most_related_tags[9] = (str(i['tag']), str(ij['tag']), correlation)
```

You set values of a structured array by:

```
by indexing element by record number and field name
by setting all values of a field with an array or list
by setting a record with a tuple of values
by setting multiple records with a list of tuples.
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted an array of items containing three fields. Thank you a lot